# How to exclude a specific folder within an Nx monorepo library during 'nx affected:test' command

Tags: javascript, glob, monorepo, nrwl, nx-monorepo

Problem:

I work in an Nx monorepo with multiple apps and libraries. One of my libraries (lib-b) has an assets folder that contains non-testable resources. When I make changes inside the assets folder and run npx nx affected:test, it triggers tests for all apps and libraries instead of recognizing that no code changes were made.

**Project Structure:**

```
 Monorepo
|  apps
| |  app A,B,C
|  libs
| |  lib-a
| |  lib-b
| | |  assets
```

**.nxignore Configuration:**

```
libs/lib-b/assets
```

**Expected Behaviour:**

When adding something to `lib-b/assets` and running `npx nx affected:test` should not launch any tests since no code changes occurred.

**Actual Result:**

Tests are executed for all apps and libraries.

*Notes:*

If I modify from `libs/lib-b/assets` to `libs/lib-b`, then no tests run as expected.
Any guidance on how to properly configure .nxignore or suggestions to achieve the desired behavior would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!